# VersionNt not working on Windows 7 SP1 32 bit

Tags: wix, burn

Our install package was working recently with the below versionNt condition, but has since stopped working - I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what has happened!! When i try and test it it appears that the WindowsNt value is appearing as less than 600, which doesnt sound right?

```
<util:FileSearch Id="searchSystem" Path="[SystemFolder]\advapi32.dll" Variable="FILEVERSION" Result="version"/>

<bal:Condition Message="This application is only supported on Windows 7 SP1 or above">
  <![CDATA[(VersionNT > 601) OR (VersionNT = 601 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1) OR (FILEVERSION > "6.3.10000.0")]]>
</bal:Condition>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the Burn bootstrapper those values are incorrect. As the documentation says, these values for VersionNT would be v6.01.

[Wix Burn variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html)